# Stripe difference about `setup_future_usage: "off_session"` and `confirmCardSetup` if I just want to save user's credit card when buying

Tags: stripe-payments

If I want to save user's card for future usage, I have noticed two options

1. `confirmCardSetup` - This definitely can save user's card
2. `setup_future_usage: "off_session"` inside `confirmCardPayment` - I just found out, this can also save user's card

If I only want to have a checkbox for the user to check `Remember This Card` **when buying**, then which method should I use it properly?

What's the difference between these two?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> If I only want to have a checkbox for the user to check Remember This Card when buying, then which method should I use it properly?

You would use `setup_future_usage` for this and complete the payment using only a PaymentIntent, it's exactly what it's intended for. It ensures that the card is set up during the payment in the optimised way.

https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-during-payment

[image]

> What's the difference between these two?

You'd only use a SetupIntent(`confirmCardSetup`) directly if you are saving the card outside the context of a payment. It allows for a 'non-payment' 3D Secure authentication to happen, which helps ensure the success of future payments. You don't need to do that explicitly when there's a payment happening though, since `setup_future_usage` is giving you exactly the same benefit.

https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-and-reuse

[image]

You simply use SetupIntents when not making a payment, and PaymentIntents when you are.

Comment: What info should I save for a re-charge? In other words, if the customer comes back and wants to buy another product, how would I re-use the CC? What info would I need to save from a PaymentIntent object?

I ask b/c I've read we shouldn't save the clientSecret, but if we don't save this, how else do you execute a new payment?

Comment: You would save the customer ID `cus_xxx` and the PaymentMethod ID `pm_xxx` (from `intent.payment_method`). You don't need any of the details from the PaymentIntent itself. When the time comes for the future charge, you create a new PaymentIntent and pass a customer and PaymentMethod ID to charge that saved card https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-and-reuse#web-create-payment-intent-off-session